# Error de compliación 'undefined reference to '_imp__. . .' en Qt (C++) al importar una librería

Tags: c++, qt, undefined, dll, referencias

soy un poco nuevo en la programación y tengo un problema a la hora de implementar la librería de optimización NLOPT. https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/
Estoy trabajando con Qt en Windows.
Básicamente he descargado el tar.gz que aparece en el repositorio de Github, he implementado la librería en el proyecto y he incluido los archivos .h y .hpp en el programa, pero a la hora de correr el programa me aparecen varios errores en el .hpp cuando intenta importar funciones del .h del estilo:

```
 nlopt.hpp:237: error: undefined reference to `_imp__nlopt_get_dimension'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN5nlopt3opt9alloc_tmpEv':
nlopt.hpp:237: undefined reference to `_imp__nlopt_get_dimension'
```

En concreto me aparece este problema con todas las funciones que intenta importar el .hpp del .h.
He leído algún post en Stack OverFlow del mismo problema pero no he conseguido solucionar el problema.

Dejo aquí los dos archivos (.h y .hpp). Siento mucho copiar casi todo el código pero no se muy bien que dejar sin copiar, aunque según he leído en posts el problema tiene que ver con las cabeceras de #ifndef y #define, pero no acabo de encontrar la solución.

Dejo también el enlace al repositorio de donde he descargado todos los archivos (.h, .hpp, .dll, .dll.a): https://github.com/stevengj/NLoptBuilder/releases

Este sería el nlopt.h

```
#ifndef NLOPT_H
#define NLOPT_H
#define NLOPT_DLL

#include <stddef.h>             /* for ptrdiff_t and size_t */

/* Change 0 to 1 to use stdcall convention under Win32 */
#if 0 && (defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__))
#  if defined(__GNUC__)
#    define NLOPT_STDCALL __attribute__((stdcall))
#  elif defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(_ICC) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED)
#    define NLOPT_STDCALL __stdcall
#  else
#    define NLOPT_STDCALL
#  endif
#else
#  define NLOPT_STDCALL
#endif

/* for Windows compilers, you should add a line
           #define NLOPT_DLL
   when using NLopt from a DLL, in order to do the proper
   Windows importing nonsense. */
#if defined(NLOPT_DLL) && (defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)) && !defined(__LCC__)
/* annoying Windows syntax for calling functions in a DLL */
#  if defined(NLOPT_DLL_EXPORT)
#    define NLOPT_EXTERN(T) extern __declspec(dllexport) T NLOPT_STDCALL
#  else
#    define NLOPT_EXTERN(T) extern __declspec(dllimport) T NLOPT_STDCALL
#  endif
#else
#  define NLOPT_EXTERN(T) extern T NLOPT_STDCALL
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

typedef double (*nlopt_func) (unsigned n, const double *x,
                              double *gradient, /* NULL if not needed */
                              void *func_data);

typedef void (*nlopt_mfunc) (unsigned m, double *result, unsigned n, const double *x,
                             double *gradient, /* NULL if not needed */
                             void *func_data);


typedef void (*nlopt_precond) (unsigned n, const double *x, const double *v, double *vpre, void *data);

typedef enum {
   

    NLOPT_GN_DIRECT = 0,
    NLOPT_GN_DIRECT_L,
    NLOPT_GN_DIRECT_L_RAND,
    NLOPT_GN_DIRECT_NOSCAL,
    NLOPT_GN_DIRECT_L_NOSCAL,
    NLOPT_GN_DIRECT_L_RAND_NOSCAL,

    NLOPT_GN_ORIG_DIRECT,
    NLOPT_GN_ORIG_DIRECT_L,

    NLOPT_GD_STOGO,
    NLOPT_GD_STOGO_RAND,

    NLOPT_LD_LBFGS_NOCEDAL,

    NLOPT_LD_LBFGS,

    NLOPT_LN_PRAXIS,

    NLOPT_LD_VAR1,
    NLOPT_LD_VAR2,

    NLOPT_LD_TNEWTON,
    NLOPT_LD_TNEWTON_RESTART,
    NLOPT_LD_TNEWTON_PRECOND,
    NLOPT_LD_TNEWTON_PRECOND_RESTART,

    NLOPT_GN_CRS2_LM,

    NLOPT_GN_MLSL,
    NLOPT_GD_MLSL,
    NLOPT_GN_MLSL_LDS,
    NLOPT_GD_MLSL_LDS,

    NLOPT_LD_MMA,

    NLOPT_LN_COBYLA,
    NLOPT_LN_NEWUOA,
    NLOPT_LN_NEWUOA_BOUND,
    NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD,
    NLOPT_LN_SBPLX
    NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG,
    NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG,
    NLOPT_LN_AUGLAG_EQ,
    NLOPT_LD_AUGLAG_EQ,
    NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA,
    NLOPT_GN_ISRES,
    
    NLOPT_AUGLAG,
    NLOPT_AUGLAG_EQ,
    NLOPT_G_MLSL,
    NLOPT_G_MLSL_LDS,
    NLOPT_LD_SLSQP,
    NLOPT_LD_CCSAQ,
    NLOPT_GN_ESCH
    NLOPT_GN_AGS,

    NLOPT_NUM_ALGORITHMS        
} nlopt_algorithm;

NLOPT_EXTERN(const char *) nlopt_algorithm_name(nlopt_algorithm a);

typedef enum {
    NLOPT_FAILURE = -1,         
    NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS = -2,
    NLOPT_OUT_OF_MEMORY = -3,
    NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED = -4,
    NLOPT_FORCED_STOP = -5,
    NLOPT_SUCCESS = 1,          
    NLOPT_STOPVAL_REACHED = 2,
    NLOPT_FTOL_REACHED = 3,
    NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED = 4,
    NLOPT_MAXEVAL_REACHED = 5,
    NLOPT_MAXTIME_REACHED = 6
} nlopt_result;

#define NLOPT_MINF_MAX_REACHED NLOPT_STOPVAL_REACHED

NLOPT_EXTERN(void) nlopt_srand(unsigned long seed);
NLOPT_EXTERN(void) nlopt_srand_time(void);

NLOPT_EXTERN(void) nlopt_version(int *major, int *minor, int *bugfix);

//Object OrientedApi 


struct nlopt_opt_s;             /* opaque structure, defined internally */
typedef struct nlopt_opt_s *nlopt_opt;


NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_opt) nlopt_create(nlopt_algorithm algorithm, unsigned n);
NLOPT_EXTERN(void) nlopt_destroy(nlopt_opt opt);


NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_optimize(nlopt_opt opt, double *x, double *opt_f);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_min_objective(nlopt_opt opt, nlopt_func f, void *f_data);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_max_objective(nlopt_opt opt, nlopt_func f, void *f_data);


NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_algorithm) nlopt_get_algorithm(const nlopt_opt opt);
NLOPT_EXTERN(unsigned) nlopt_get_dimension(const nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(const char *) nlopt_get_errmsg(nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_lower_bounds(nlopt_opt opt, const double *lb);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_lower_bounds1(nlopt_opt opt, double lb);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_lower_bound(nlopt_opt opt, int i, double lb);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_get_lower_bounds(const nlopt_opt opt, double *lb);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_upper_bounds(nlopt_opt opt, const double *ub);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_upper_bounds1(nlopt_opt opt, double ub);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_upper_bound(nlopt_opt opt, int i, double ub);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_get_upper_bounds(const nlopt_opt opt, double *ub);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_remove_inequality_constraints(nlopt_opt opt);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_add_inequality_constraint(nlopt_opt opt, nlopt_func fc, void *fc_data, double tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_add_precond_inequality_constraint(nlopt_opt opt, nlopt_func fc, nlopt_precond pre, void *fc_data, double tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint(nlopt_opt opt, unsigned m, nlopt_mfunc fc, void *fc_data, const double *tol);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_remove_equality_constraints(nlopt_opt opt);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_add_equality_constraint(nlopt_opt opt, nlopt_func h, void *h_data, double tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_add_precond_equality_constraint(nlopt_opt opt, nlopt_func h, nlopt_precond pre, void *h_data, double tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_add_equality_mconstraint(nlopt_opt opt, unsigned m, nlopt_mfunc h, void *h_data, const double *tol);



NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_stopval(nlopt_opt opt, double stopval);
NLOPT_EXTERN(double) nlopt_get_stopval(const nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_xtol_rel(nlopt_opt opt, double tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(double) nlopt_get_xtol_rel(const nlopt_opt opt);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_xtol_abs1(nlopt_opt opt, double tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_xtol_abs(nlopt_opt opt, const double *tol);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_get_xtol_abs(const nlopt_opt opt, double *tol);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_maxeval(nlopt_opt opt, int maxeval);
NLOPT_EXTERN(int) nlopt_get_maxeval(const nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(int) nlopt_get_numevals(const nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_maxtime(nlopt_opt opt, double maxtime);
NLOPT_EXTERN(double) nlopt_get_maxtime(const nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_force_stop(nlopt_opt opt);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_force_stop(nlopt_opt opt, int val);
NLOPT_EXTERN(int) nlopt_get_force_stop(const nlopt_opt opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_local_optimizer(nlopt_opt opt, const nlopt_opt local_opt);

NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_default_initial_step(nlopt_opt opt, const double *x);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_initial_step(nlopt_opt opt, const double *dx);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_set_initial_step1(nlopt_opt opt, double dx);
NLOPT_EXTERN(nlopt_result) nlopt_get_initial_step(const nlopt_opt opt, const double *x, double *dx);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  /* extern "C" */
#endif /* __cplusplus */
#endif
```

y este sería el nlopt.hpp

```
#ifndef NLOPT_HPP
#define NLOPT_HPP
#include <nlopt.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
// convenience overloading for below (not in nlopt:: since has nlopt_ prefix)
inline nlopt_result nlopt_get_initial_step(const nlopt_opt opt, double *dx) {
      return nlopt_get_initial_step(opt, (const double *) NULL, dx);
}
namespace nlopt {
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // nlopt::* namespace versions of the C enumerated types
  //          AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED, DO NOT EDIT
  // GEN_ENUMS_HERE
  enum algorithm {
    GN_DIRECT = 0,
    GN_DIRECT_L,
    GN_DIRECT_L_RAND,
    GN_DIRECT_NOSCAL,
    GN_DIRECT_L_NOSCAL,
    GN_DIRECT_L_RAND_NOSCAL,
    GN_ORIG_DIRECT,
    GN_ORIG_DIRECT_L,
    GD_STOGO,
    GD_STOGO_RAND,
    LD_LBFGS_NOCEDAL,
    LD_LBFGS,
    LN_PRAXIS,
    LD_VAR1,
    LD_VAR2,
    LD_TNEWTON,
    LD_TNEWTON_RESTART,
    LD_TNEWTON_PRECOND,
    LD_TNEWTON_PRECOND_RESTART,
    GN_CRS2_LM,
    GN_MLSL,
    GD_MLSL,
    GN_MLSL_LDS,
    GD_MLSL_LDS,
    LD_MMA,
    LN_COBYLA,
    LN_NEWUOA,
    LN_NEWUOA_BOUND,
    LN_NELDERMEAD,
    LN_SBPLX,
    LN_AUGLAG,
    LD_AUGLAG,
    LN_AUGLAG_EQ,
    LD_AUGLAG_EQ,
    LN_BOBYQA,
    GN_ISRES,
    AUGLAG,
    AUGLAG_EQ,
    G_MLSL,
    G_MLSL_LDS,
    LD_SLSQP,
    LD_CCSAQ,
    GN_ESCH,
    GN_AGS,
    NUM_ALGORITHMS        /* not an algorithm, just the number of them */
  };
  enum result {
    FAILURE = -1,         /* generic failure code */
    INVALID_ARGS = -2,
    OUT_OF_MEMORY = -3,
    ROUNDOFF_LIMITED = -4,
    FORCED_STOP = -5,
    SUCCESS = 1,          /* generic success code */
    STOPVAL_REACHED = 2,
    FTOL_REACHED = 3,
    XTOL_REACHED = 4,
    MAXEVAL_REACHED = 5,
    MAXTIME_REACHED = 6
  };
  //
  typedef nlopt_func func; // nlopt::func synoynm
  typedef nlopt_mfunc mfunc; // nlopt::mfunc synoynm
  // alternative to nlopt_func that takes std::vector<double>
  // ... unfortunately requires a data copy
  typedef double (*vfunc)(const std::vector<double> &x,
              std::vector<double> &grad, void *data);
  //
  
  // NLopt-specific exceptions (corresponding to error codes):
  class roundoff_limited : public std::runtime_error {
  public:
    roundoff_limited() : std::runtime_error("nlopt roundoff-limited") {}
  };
  class forced_stop : public std::runtime_error {
  public:
    forced_stop() : std::runtime_error("nlopt forced stop") {}
  };
  //
  class opt {
  private:
    nlopt_opt o;
    
    void mythrow(nlopt_result ret) const {
      switch (ret) {
      case NLOPT_FAILURE: throw std::runtime_error(get_errmsg() ? get_errmsg() : "nlopt failure");
      case NLOPT_OUT_OF_MEMORY: throw std::bad_alloc();
      case NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS: throw std::invalid_argument(get_errmsg() ? get_errmsg() : "nlopt invalid argument");
      case NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED: throw roundoff_limited();
      case NLOPT_FORCED_STOP: throw forced_stop();
      default: break;
      }
    }
    typedef struct {
      opt *o;
      mfunc mf; func f; void *f_data;
      vfunc vf;
      nlopt_munge munge_destroy, munge_copy; // non-NULL for SWIG wrappers
    } myfunc_data;
    // free/destroy f_data in nlopt_destroy and nlopt_copy, respectively
    static void *free_myfunc_data(void *p) { 
      myfunc_data *d = (myfunc_data *) p;
      if (d) {
    if (d->f_data && d->munge_destroy) d->munge_destroy(d->f_data);
    delete d;
      }
      return NULL;
    }
    static void *dup_myfunc_data(void *p) {
      myfunc_data *d = (myfunc_data *) p;
      if (d) {
    void *f_data;
    if (d->f_data && d->munge_copy) {
      f_data = d->munge_copy(d->f_data);
      if (!f_data) return NULL;
    }
    else
      f_data = d->f_data;
    myfunc_data *dnew = new myfunc_data;
    if (dnew) {
      *dnew = *d;
      dnew->f_data = f_data;
    }
    return (void*) dnew;
      }
      else return NULL;
    }
    // nlopt_func wrapper that catches exceptions
    static double myfunc(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *d_) {
      myfunc_data *d = reinterpret_cast<myfunc_data*>(d_);
      try {
    return d->f(n, x, grad, d->f_data);
      }
      catch (std::bad_alloc&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_OUT_OF_MEMORY; }
      catch (std::invalid_argument&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS; }
      catch (roundoff_limited&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED; }
      catch (forced_stop&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FORCED_STOP; }
      catch (...)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FAILURE; }
      d->o->force_stop(); // stop gracefully, opt::optimize will re-throw
      return HUGE_VAL;
    }
    // nlopt_mfunc wrapper that catches exceptions
    static void mymfunc(unsigned m, double *result,
            unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *d_) {
      myfunc_data *d = reinterpret_cast<myfunc_data*>(d_);
      try {
    d->mf(m, result, n, x, grad, d->f_data);
    return;
      }
      catch (std::bad_alloc&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_OUT_OF_MEMORY; }
      catch (std::invalid_argument&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS; }
      catch (roundoff_limited&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED; }
      catch (forced_stop&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FORCED_STOP; }
      catch (...)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FAILURE; }
      d->o->force_stop(); // stop gracefully, opt::optimize will re-throw
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < m; ++i) result[i] = HUGE_VAL;
    }
    std::vector<double> xtmp, gradtmp, gradtmp0; // scratch for myvfunc
    // nlopt_func wrapper, using std::vector<double>
    static double myvfunc(unsigned n, const double *x, double *grad, void *d_){
      myfunc_data *d = reinterpret_cast<myfunc_data*>(d_);
      try {
    std::vector<double> &xv = d->o->xtmp;
    if (n) std::memcpy(&xv[0], x, n * sizeof(double));
    double val=d->vf(xv, grad ? d->o->gradtmp : d->o->gradtmp0, d->f_data);
    if (grad && n) {
      std::vector<double> &gradv = d->o->gradtmp;
      std::memcpy(grad, &gradv[0], n * sizeof(double));
    }
    return val;
      }
      catch (std::bad_alloc&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_OUT_OF_MEMORY; }
      catch (std::invalid_argument&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_INVALID_ARGS; }
      catch (roundoff_limited&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_ROUNDOFF_LIMITED; }
      catch (forced_stop&)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FORCED_STOP; }
      catch (...)
    { d->o->forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FAILURE; }
      d->o->force_stop(); // stop gracefully, opt::optimize will re-throw
      return HUGE_VAL;
    }
    void alloc_tmp() {
      if (xtmp.size() != nlopt_get_dimension(o)) {
    xtmp = std::vector<double>(nlopt_get_dimension(o));
    gradtmp = std::vector<double>(nlopt_get_dimension(o));
      }
    }
    result last_result;
    double last_optf;
    nlopt_result forced_stop_reason;
  public:
    // Constructors etc.
    opt() : o(NULL), xtmp(0), gradtmp(0), gradtmp0(0), 
        last_result(nlopt::FAILURE), last_optf(HUGE_VAL),
        forced_stop_reason(NLOPT_FORCED_STOP) {}
    ~opt() { nlopt_destroy(o); }
    opt(algorithm a, unsigned n) : 
      o(nlopt_create(nlopt_algorithm(a), n)), 
      xtmp(0), gradtmp(0), gradtmp0(0),
      last_result(nlopt::FAILURE), last_optf(HUGE_VAL),
      forced_stop_reason(NLOPT_FORCED_STOP) {
      if (!o) throw std::bad_alloc();
      nlopt_set_munge(o, free_myfunc_data, dup_myfunc_data);
    }
    opt(const opt& f) : o(nlopt_copy(f.o)), 
            xtmp(f.xtmp), gradtmp(f.gradtmp), gradtmp0(0),
            last_result(f.last_result), last_optf(f.last_optf),
            forced_stop_reason(f.forced_stop_reason) {
      if (f.o && !o) throw std::bad_alloc();
    }
    opt& operator=(opt const& f) {
      if (this == &f) return *this; // self-assignment
      nlopt_destroy(o);
      o = nlopt_copy(f.o);
      if (f.o && !o) throw std::bad_alloc();
      xtmp = f.xtmp; gradtmp = f.gradtmp;
      last_result = f.last_result; last_optf = f.last_optf;
      forced_stop_reason = f.forced_stop_reason;
      return *this;
    }
    // Do the optimization:
    result optimize(std::vector<double> &x, double &opt_f) {
      if (o && nlopt_get_dimension(o) != x.size())
        throw std::invalid_argument("dimension mismatch");
      forced_stop_reason = NLOPT_FORCED_STOP;
      nlopt_result ret = nlopt_optimize(o, x.empty() ? NULL : &x[0], &opt_f);
      last_result = result(ret);
      last_optf = opt_f;
      if (ret == NLOPT_FORCED_STOP)
    mythrow(forced_stop_reason);
      mythrow(ret);
      return last_result;
    }
    // variant mainly useful for SWIG wrappers:
    std::vector<double> optimize(const std::vector<double> &x0) {
      std::vector<double> x(x0);
      last_result = optimize(x, last_optf);
      return x;
    }
    result last_optimize_result() const { return last_result; }
    double last_optimum_value() const { return last_optf; }
    // accessors:
    algorithm get_algorithm() const {
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt");
      return algorithm(nlopt_get_algorithm(o));
    }
    const char *get_algorithm_name() const {
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt");
      return nlopt_algorithm_name(nlopt_get_algorithm(o));
    }
    unsigned get_dimension() const {
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt");
      return nlopt_get_dimension(o);
    }
    // Set the objective function
    void set_min_objective(func f, void *f_data) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_set_min_objective(o, myfunc, d)); // d freed via o
    }
    void set_min_objective(vfunc vf, void *f_data) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = NULL; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = vf;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_set_min_objective(o, myvfunc, d)); // d freed via o
      alloc_tmp();
    }
    void set_max_objective(func f, void *f_data) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_set_max_objective(o, myfunc, d)); // d freed via o
    }
    void set_max_objective(vfunc vf, void *f_data) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = NULL; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = vf;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_set_max_objective(o, myvfunc, d)); // d freed via o
      alloc_tmp();
    }
    // for internal use in SWIG wrappers -- variant that
    // takes ownership of f_data, with munging for destroy/copy
    void set_min_objective(func f, void *f_data,
               nlopt_munge md, nlopt_munge mc) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = md; d->munge_copy = mc;
      mythrow(nlopt_set_min_objective(o, myfunc, d)); // d freed via o
    }
    void set_max_objective(func f, void *f_data,
               nlopt_munge md, nlopt_munge mc) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = md; d->munge_copy = mc;
      mythrow(nlopt_set_max_objective(o, myfunc, d)); // d freed via o
    }
    // Nonlinear constraints:
    void remove_inequality_constraints() {
      nlopt_result ret = nlopt_remove_inequality_constraints(o);
      mythrow(ret);
    }
    void add_inequality_constraint(func f, void *f_data, double tol=0) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_inequality_constraint(o, myfunc, d, tol));
    }
    void add_inequality_constraint(vfunc vf, void *f_data, double tol=0) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = NULL; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = vf;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_inequality_constraint(o, myvfunc, d, tol));
      alloc_tmp();
    }
    void add_inequality_mconstraint(mfunc mf, void *f_data, 
                    const std::vector<double> &tol) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->mf = mf; d->f_data = f_data; d->f = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint(o, tol.size(), mymfunc, d, 
                           tol.empty() ? NULL : &tol[0]));
    }
    void remove_equality_constraints() {
      nlopt_result ret = nlopt_remove_equality_constraints(o);
      mythrow(ret);
    }
    void add_equality_constraint(func f, void *f_data, double tol=0) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_equality_constraint(o, myfunc, d, tol));
    }
    void add_equality_constraint(vfunc vf, void *f_data, double tol=0) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = NULL; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = vf;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_equality_constraint(o, myvfunc, d, tol));
      alloc_tmp();
    }
    void add_equality_mconstraint(mfunc mf, void *f_data, 
                  const std::vector<double> &tol) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->mf = mf; d->f_data = f_data; d->f = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = d->munge_copy = NULL;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_equality_mconstraint(o, tol.size(), mymfunc, d, 
                         tol.empty() ? NULL : &tol[0]));
    }
    // For internal use in SWIG wrappers (see also above)
    void add_inequality_constraint(func f, void *f_data, 
                   nlopt_munge md, nlopt_munge mc,
                   double tol=0) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = md; d->munge_copy = mc;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_inequality_constraint(o, myfunc, d, tol));
    }
    void add_equality_constraint(func f, void *f_data, 
                 nlopt_munge md, nlopt_munge mc,
                 double tol=0) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->f = f; d->f_data = f_data; d->mf = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = md; d->munge_copy = mc;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_equality_constraint(o, myfunc, d, tol));
    }
    void add_inequality_mconstraint(mfunc mf, void *f_data, 
                    nlopt_munge md, nlopt_munge mc,
                    const std::vector<double> &tol) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->mf = mf; d->f_data = f_data; d->f = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = md; d->munge_copy = mc;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_inequality_mconstraint(o, tol.size(), mymfunc, d, 
                           tol.empty() ? NULL : &tol[0]));
    }
    void add_equality_mconstraint(mfunc mf, void *f_data, 
                  nlopt_munge md, nlopt_munge mc,
                  const std::vector<double> &tol) {
      myfunc_data *d = new myfunc_data;
      if (!d) throw std::bad_alloc();
      d->o = this; d->mf = mf; d->f_data = f_data; d->f = NULL; d->vf = NULL;
      d->munge_destroy = md; d->munge_copy = mc;
      mythrow(nlopt_add_equality_mconstraint(o, tol.size(), mymfunc, d, 
                         tol.empty() ? NULL : &tol[0]));
    }
#define NLOPT_GETSET_VEC(name)                       \
    void set_##name(double val) {                    \
      mythrow(nlopt_set_##name##1(o, val)); \
    }                                    \
    void get_##name(std::vector<double> &v) const {          \
      if (o && nlopt_get_dimension(o) != v.size())           \
        throw std::invalid_argument("dimension mismatch"); \
      mythrow(nlopt_get_##name(o, v.empty() ? NULL : &v[0])); \
    }                                    \
    std::vector<double> get_##name() const {             \
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt"); \
      std::vector<double> v(nlopt_get_dimension(o)); \
      get_##name(v); \
      return v; \
    }                                    \
    void set_##name(const std::vector<double> &v) {          \
      if (o && nlopt_get_dimension(o) != v.size())           \
        throw std::invalid_argument("dimension mismatch"); \
      mythrow(nlopt_set_##name(o, v.empty() ? NULL : &v[0])); \
    }
    NLOPT_GETSET_VEC(lower_bounds)
    NLOPT_GETSET_VEC(upper_bounds)
    // stopping criteria:
#define NLOPT_GETSET(T, name)                        \
    T get_##name() const {                       \
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt"); \
      return nlopt_get_##name(o); \
    }                                    \
    void set_##name(T name) {                        \
      mythrow(nlopt_set_##name(o, name)); \
    }
    NLOPT_GETSET(double, stopval)
    NLOPT_GETSET(double, ftol_rel)
    NLOPT_GETSET(double, ftol_abs)
    NLOPT_GETSET(double, xtol_rel)
    NLOPT_GETSET_VEC(xtol_abs)
    NLOPT_GETSET(int, maxeval)
    int get_numevals() const {
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt");
      return nlopt_get_numevals(o);
    }
    NLOPT_GETSET(double, maxtime)
    NLOPT_GETSET(int, force_stop)
    void force_stop() { set_force_stop(1); }
    const char *get_errmsg() const { 
        if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt");
        return nlopt_get_errmsg(o);
    }
    // algorithm-specific parameters:
    void set_local_optimizer(const opt &lo) {
      nlopt_result ret = nlopt_set_local_optimizer(o, lo.o);
      mythrow(ret);
    }
    NLOPT_GETSET(unsigned, population)
    NLOPT_GETSET(unsigned, vector_storage)
    NLOPT_GETSET_VEC(initial_step)
    void set_default_initial_step(const std::vector<double> &x) {
      nlopt_result ret 
    = nlopt_set_default_initial_step(o, x.empty() ? NULL : &x[0]);
      mythrow(ret);
    }
    void get_initial_step(const std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &dx) const {
      if (o && (nlopt_get_dimension(o) != x.size()
        || nlopt_get_dimension(o) != dx.size()))
        throw std::invalid_argument("dimension mismatch");
      nlopt_result ret = nlopt_get_initial_step(o, x.empty() ? NULL : &x[0],
                        dx.empty() ? NULL : &dx[0]);
      mythrow(ret);
    }
    std::vector<double> get_initial_step_(const std::vector<double> &x) const {
      if (!o) throw std::runtime_error("uninitialized nlopt::opt");
      std::vector<double> v(nlopt_get_dimension(o));
      get_initial_step(x, v);
      return v;
    }
  };
#undef NLOPT_GETSET
#undef NLOPT_GETSET_VEC
 
} // namespace nlopt
#endif /* NLOPT_HPP */
```

El cpp.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<nlopt.hpp>
#include<nlopt.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace nlopt;



double myfunc(const vector<double>&x, vector<double>&grad, void *my_func_data) {
    grad[0] = 1 / x[0];
    grad[1] = 1 / x[1];
    return log(x[0]) + log(x[1]);
}

double myconstraint(const vector<double>&x, vector<double>&grad, void *my_data) {
    double *p = (double *)my_data;
    grad[0] = p[0];
    grad[1] = p[1];
    return x[0] * p[0] + x[1] * p[1] - 5;
}

double myinconstraint(const vector<double>&x, vector<double>&grad, void *my_data) {

    grad[0] = 1;
    grad[1] = -1;
    return x[0] - x[1];
}


int main() {
    double f_max = -10000;
    double tol = 1e-8;
    double p[2] = { 1,2 };
    vector<double> x{ 1,1 };
     opt opter (LD_SLSQP, 2); // Define an optimizer, use SLSQP algorithm, two optimization dimensions
    opter.set_max_objective(myfunc, NULL);
    vector<double> lb{ 0,0 };
    vector<double> rb{ 10000,10000 };
    opter.set_lower_bounds(lb);
    opter.set_upper_bounds(rb);
    opter.add_equality_constraint(myconstraint, p,tol);
    opter.add_inequality_constraint(myinconstraint, NULL,tol);
    opter.set_xtol_rel(tol);
    opter.set_force_stop(tol);

    result res = opter.optimize(x,f_max);
    cout << x[0] << ends << x[1] << ends << f_max << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Hola, he probado a introducir únicamente el archivo .hpp pero siguen apareciendo los mismos errores. Respecto a lo de los namespaces, no se cómo no utilizarlos ya que la propia librería funciona con ellos

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido reportada automáticamente por el sistema debido a su extensión. No necesitas tomar ninguna medida en el momento, pero lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] e intenta que tus futuras preguntas no sean tan extensas.